# Add list to Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, random, graph

I am doing a randomly generated world and I'm starting of with basic graphing trying to be similar to Perlin Noise. I did everything and the last thing that I've written (important one) did work.

```
import math
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print('ur seed')
a = input()
seed = int(a)
b = (math.cos(seed) * 100)
c = round(b)
# print(c)
for i in range(10):
   z = (random.randint(-1, 2))
   change = (z + c)
   gener = []
   gener.append(change)
   time = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
   #print(gener)

   #print(change)
   plt.ylabel('generated')
   plt.xlabel('time')
   #Here I wanna add them to the graph and it is Erroring a lot
   plt.scatter(time, gener)
   plt.title('graph')
   plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you're setting `gener` to `[]` in the loop not out of the loop. also, you don't need the `time` variable inside the loop either.

change

```
for i in range(10):
    z = (random.randint(-1, 2))
    change = (z + c)
    gener = []
    gener.append(change)
    time = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

to

```
gener = []
for i in range(10):
    z = (random.randint(-1, 2))
    change = (z + c)
    gener.append(change)
time = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```